# Azure Data Factory error on IT: "Only an Azure integration runtime with 'Auto Resolve' location can be used in Data Flow Activity."

Tags: azure-data-factory

Since Azure have some problems due to CoronaVirus, I try to run my dataflow on a separate IR, but I get the following message:
"Only an Azure integration runtime with 'Auto Resolve' location can be used in Data Flow Activity."

I tried to change the default Integration runtime, but it's not editable. The point is that I am trying to change the region more close to mine and give more compute power...

Anyone anyidea

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at allowing Azure IR for data flows to pin to specific regions instead of only "Auto Resolve".

In the interim, you can export your Data Factory and import the factory, or use your Git repo, to move the factory to another region.

That will allow the data flow Azure IR to spin-up compute in another region.